# How do I go about forecasting sales data using prophet on Snowpark for sparse data?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-3.8

I am writing Snowpark code via Python worksheets in Snowsight. To be explicit, I am not using third-party IDEs or any notebook for doing so but using the Python worksheets provided via Snowsight.
My data is for sales of products of a healthcare company. The data contains a time element (column) that specifies what week the sale was made (takes the Sunday as the first day of the week, and the date on the Sunday corresponds to the label for that week). The data contains multiple products; each unique product is a time series for training on the Prophet model. However, some products (timeseries) have sparse data, i.e., the number of data points for those products is less(less than or equal to 10 weeks, which means 10 data points). So, when I try to train the model because Snowpark uses distributed computing on Snowflake, I get an error for some products saying - "less than or equal to 2 data points". I assume that this ensues because the training for a single timeseries (product) is spread across different nodes, with some  nodes getting 1 or 2 data points to train on. I think using a UDTF to send train all the data points for a timeseries at a single node could be a way to accomplish this, but I am pretty new to Snowflake and Snowpark and not sure how to use UDTFs or if that would even be a solution to the problem.

Here is a sample of the input data:

| product_id | order_date | sales_vol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AJ98 | 7/3/22 | 2 |
| AJ98 | 7/10/22 | 3 |
| AJ98 | 8/4/22 | 45 |
| AJ98 | 9/4/22 | 32 |
| AJ98 | 10/21/22 | 3 |
| S785 | 7/7/22 | 6 |
| S785 | 8/10/22 | 45 |
| S785 | 8/14/22 | 23 |
| S785 | 11/26/22 | 65 |
| S785 | 12/11/22 | 5 |
| V54 | 7/30/22 | 22 |
| V54 | 8/17/22 | 2 |
| V54 | 9/7/22 | 25 |
| V54 | 11/22/22 | 76 |
| V54 | 12/3/22 | 12 |

Each unique product_id (AJ98, S785, V54) is to be treated as a separate timeseries and used to train the prophet model.
What I need is a UDTF or any other way that circumvents the problem specified above (use the complete timeseries for training and parallelize across distinct timeseries instead of datapoints within a single timeseries)

I am currently using a couple of UDFs- one to preprocess the data and get it in the desired format for the prophet model and the other to send the data for training on all the unique products/ time series and generate forecasts for future sales of those products. This, in my opinion, is giving the error- "two or less than two data points for prophet" as the data points within the time series with sparse data are also distributed and trained concurrently on different nodes.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you missed tagging the experts on Prophet. They would be the best at understanding how to use Prophet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-prophet